# What's the difference between while(--i); and while(i) --i;?

Tags: c++, while-loop, post-increment, pre-increment

My first submission of [61.Rotate List](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-list/) ran for 16 ms and I was not happy with that. So I changed this part of my code

```
k += 1;
while (--k) {
    p = p->next;
}
```

to

```
while (k) {
    p = p->next;
    --k;
}
```

and then magic happened. Runtime decreased to 8 ms.

So what's the difference between them? Why the runtime gap is so large?

Comment: You mean besides *when* `k` is decremented?

Comment: And please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please try to create an [mcve] to show us.

Comment: These codes are equivalent, unless `k+=1` causes integer overflow

Comment: I wouldn’t use leetcode to judge efficiency of your code if I were you

Comment: G++ sees no difference with -O1. Did you forget to toggle code optimization when doing bench-marking?

Comment: A difference of 8ms isn't really measurable and is affected by many things outside of your control.

Comment: as there is a "As if" rule which compiler can utilize, I wouldn't be surprised if generated code has no differences for those two.

Comment: What is the type of `k`? You should also try with `while(k--) p = p->next;`.  But this also dependes on the use of `k` after the loop.

Comment: @DeiDei 8ms is not measurable?? Its not huge, but of course it can be measured

Comment: With -O1 it results into the exact same assemblycode... https://godbolt.org/z/d3YrBx

Comment: Maybe unrelated: making directly a rotation of order _k_ should be more efficient than performing _k_ rotations of order _1_

Answer (score 3):

This is probably just a compiler quirk or a benchmarking error. Code segments that produce identical results under all circumstances should theoretically compile to the same assembly. Usually the compiler fails to optimize if parts of the code are obfuscated (eg in different translation units) or if the code segment is complex enough that the optimizer fails to see the equivalency.

In this particular case, there should be no problem. Indeed, GCC compiles these segments to the same assembly.

```
struct P {
    P* next;
};

P* func1(unsigned int k, P* p) {
    k += 1;
    while (--k) {
        p = p->next;
    }
    return p;
}

P* func2(unsigned int k, P* p) {
    while (k) {
        p = p->next;
        --k;
    }
    return p;
}
```

The assembly output is

```
func1(unsigned int, P*):
movq %rsi, %rax
testl %edi, %edi
je .L2
.L3:
movq (%rax), %rax
subl $1, %edi
jne .L3
.L2:
ret
func2(unsigned int, P*):
movq %rsi, %rax
testl %edi, %edi
je .L10
.L11:
movq (%rax), %rax
subl $1, %edi
jne .L11
.L10:
ret
```

Jump labels aside, the assembly for those functions is identical. You can view it in godbolt [here](https://godbolt.org/z/_NI8V6).

Comment: Well, the C++ code in each function is exactly the same.

Comment: @MikeBorkland Thanks for pointing that out. I messed up when copy-pasting, but I fixed it now.